# Некорректное подключение JQuery в Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

При подключении плагина в записи вордпресса, плагин не видит jQuery и консоль, естественно, отвечает:

```
jQuery(...).rotator is not a function
```

В той же записи прямо перед подключением плагина висит:

```
<script> if (window.jQuery) {
 alert('ss');
}
</script>
```

Который возвращает ss.

Подключал в functions.php, по-неправильному в header.php, устанавливал плагин для подключения jquery на страницах - всё равно не работает.

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Код с подключением плагина, равно как и jquery даст больше информации для ответа на вопрос.

Если есть плагины, требуещие jquery и в html они объявлены раньше - то примерно такую ошибку консоль возвращать и будет.